# .forEach returns unexpected results when using isNaN(foo) and typeof foo !== number

Tags: javascript, foreach

The title of this post might not be appropriate, but I'm having difficulties trying to explain my issue in a more detailed way. Said issue was fixed, but I do not understand why it happened.

I previously had this code:

```
var SumElements = (arr) => {
    let count = 0;
    let ignored = [];

    arr.forEach(i => {
        if(isNaN(i)) {
            ignored.push(i);
            return;
        }

        count = count + i;
        console.log(count);
    });

    return [count, ignored];

}
```

This was my test case: `console.log(SumElements([3, "f", 3, "9", "o", 3, 1]));`

Output:

```
3
6
69
693
6931
[ '6931', [ 'f', 'o' ] ]
```

The expected output was: `[10, ['f', '9', 'o']]`.

I proceeded to change `isNaN(i)` to `typeof i !== "number"` and the output was the expected `[ 10, [ 'f', '9', 'o' ] ]`.

Why did I get the weird results in the first revision of the code?

Comment: I think I kind of see it now. "9" is a string and it turned the 6 (3+3, first two iterations) into a string when "9" was appended. Since `count` is now a string, 3 and 1 got appended to that string. My question is: why was "9" interpreted as a number?

Answer (score 1):

`isNaN("9")` is false. See the [docs for isNaN, under the 'confusing behaviour' section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Confusing_special-case_behavior) .

Checking with `typeof i !== 'number'` is better for catching strings, but you need to do both to check for the actual `NaN` value, becuase `typeof NaN === 'number'`.

Answer (score 1):

> You should use  `count = count + Number(i);`
>
> because `forEach` return index in the string format

```
var SumElements = (arr) => {
    let count = 0;
    let ignored = [];

    arr.forEach(i => {
        console.log(typeof i); // "string" not ok(

        i = Number(i); // because forEach return index in string

        console.log(typeof i); // "number" ok

        if(isNaN(i)) {
            ignored.push(i);
            return;
        }

        count = count + i; 
        console.log(count);
    });

    return [count, ignored];

}
```